# Flutter dealing with state after back button

Tags: flutter

I have an article page which has 2 sections

- a button to subscribe / unsubscribe the publisher (works fine with cubit)
- related news (clicking on related news will push a new article page on top of the existing one)

Here's the cubit for the subscribe button

```
class SubscriptionCubit extends Cubit<SubscriptionState> {
  final ArticleDataSource _articleDataSource;

  SubscriptionCubit(this._articleDataSource, bool subscribed)
      : super(SubscriptionStatus(subscribed));

  void toggle(String publisherId) async {
    emit(SubscriptionLoading());
    bool isSubscribed = await _articleDataSource.followPublisher(publisherId);
    emit(SubscriptionStatus(isSubscribed));
  }
}
```

My article page

```
class ArticlePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String timezone = DateTime.now().timeZoneName;
  final Duration timezoneOffset = DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset;
  final String id;

  ArticlePage({Key key, @required this.id}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        child: BlocProvider<ArticleBloc>(
          create: (context) => ArticleBloc(
              articleDataSource:
              RepositoryProvider.of<ArticleDataSource>(context),
              articleId: id)
            ..add(Fetch(id: this.id)),
          child: BlocBuilder<ArticleBloc, ArticleState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is ArticleLoaded) {
                return drawArticle(context, state);
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The issue I am facing is with the following scenario:

1. Go to **Article A1** from **Publisher A** (I am not subscribed yet at this point)
2. On Related News section, I click on **Article A2**  (from the same **Publisher A**)
3. I press the subscribe button (button got updated to `subscribed`)
4. Then I pressed the (default) back button and now I am back at the Article A1

The problem is the displayed button on this screen is still the old one `unsubsribed` instead of `subscribed`.

UPDATED with GIF

[image]

How should I update the "old" subscribe button after pressing the back button ?